# Apache - Can't connect to specific VHost

Tags: apache, localhost, vhosts, hosts

I configured Apache, SQL and PHPMyAdmin on my mac (high sierra). Everything is working fine except I can't seem to use my vhost address for some reason.

Here are the line of codes I edited to make use of vhost:

/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/
</VirtualHost>


# http://localhost/ethospractice.cms.com/web/
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/ethospractice.cms.com/web/
    ServerName craft3.ethospractice.test
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/ethospractice.cms.com/web/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I uncomented the following line on /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and change de RootDirectory to serve my Sites folder as follow:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then I added this to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 craft3.ethospractice.test
```

When I go to craft3.ethospractice.test it says that the site can't be reached.
But if I go manually to the DocumentRoot (http://localhost/ethospractice.cms.com/web/) directory that I specified for that host, the site is served without any problems. 
My localhosts works fine. If I go to localhost it serves my Sites folder.

So I have no idea why my vhost configuration is not working. I have surfed the internet for two days and haven't found any solution.

Comment: When you go to a command line and restart Apache, does it throw any errors? If you just go to "localhost" does it show the site you wanted?

Comment: @mrunion It doesn't throw any errors. When I go to "localhost" it serves my "Sites" folder ad expected since I configured it this way

Answer (score 0):

For this You have to follow three steps .

1. Add virtual host code in httpd-vhosts.conf

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName craft3.ethospractice.test
>     DocumentRoot "C:/xamppneww/htdocs/craft_home/craft_revision/web"
>     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
>     <Directory "C:/xamppneww/htdocs/craft_home/craft_revision/web">
>         DirectoryIndex index.php
>         AllowOverride All
>         Order allow,deny
>         Allow from all
>     </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

2. Mention your servername in hosts file

> ```
> #127.0.0.1 localhost
> 127.0.0.1 craft3.ethospractice.test
> ```

3. Restart xampp

That's all. You do not need to do anything else. If you still not getting that then it must be xampp setup or configuration related problem.